# Null-safety for fromJson like methods

Tags: json, flutter, dart-null-safety

I want to define a simple class model `UserResponse` in Flutter `2.0.5` and build a `fromJson` method attached to this class to create an instance easily after receiving the data from the backend in json format.

```
class UserResponse {
  String name;

  UserResponse ({
    required this.name,
  });

  UserResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name= json['name'].toString();
  }
}
```

The dart compiler however throws an error here:
`dart(not_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field)`

Furthermore:
Non-nullable instance field 'name' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.

If I know that I will only call the `fromJson` method if I have all the required data, how should I create the new Instance in this method? I don't want to change the `name` field in the class to `late`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065621/flutter-null-safety-with-fromjson) there are mainly to ways:

1. Use an initializer list for the method
2. Use a factory method

Thus,

```
UserResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) :
        name= json['name'] as String;
```

or

```
factory UserResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return UserResponse(
            name: json['name'] as String,
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [factory](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors) constructor.

```
class UserResponse {
  final String name;

  UserResponse({
    required this.name,
  });

  factory UserResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserResponse(name: json['name'].toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For null-safety. You need to be check **null** right way. And front-end need handle server don't return this key, we need mock data and sure app can't crash.

```
class UserResponse {
  UserResponse({
    this.name,
  });

  final String? name;

  factory UserResponse.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      UserResponse.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory UserResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserResponse(
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"].toString(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
      };
}
```

Comment: The `toJson` and `fromJson` method has some redundancy in it and the `name` variable in your model is not null-safe. This is not a response that solves the issue. Just go with my accepted answer as it fulfills the question 100%.

Comment: if JSON return from server don't have key `name` your app will be crash (expect String but got Null ..... ). My code fix this issue.

Comment: First, this was not requested. Second, no it does not. `name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"].toString(),` is for multiple reasons useless. You don't need the `toString()` method on a String. You don't need a null check for a nullable type as you declare `final String? name;` above and anyway you are just asigning `null` if it is `null`, so completely redundant.

Comment: Oh. I forgot `final String? name;` set name `null` for default. Thank you! nice.